# Using ASP.Net Identity EntityFramwork to Existing AspNetUsers table with ID Column set to UniqueIdentifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am using the Nuget package [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.1.0) and connecting to an existing SQL Server database where the AspNetUsers table ID column is set as UniqueIdentifier.

When performing a call to get the User, I am getting an error:

The 'Id' property on 'IdentityUser`4' could not be set to a 'System.Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'.

Is there a way to set the Id property in code as I can't modify the column property on my database.

Here are my code snippets:

**AuthProvider.cs**

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
  public override async Task GrantCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
  {
    using(Repository _repo = new Repository())
    {
      IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UName, context.PWord);
      if(user == null)
      {
        // User Not Found / Invalid UName or PWord.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository : IDisposable
{
  private AppContext _ctx;
  private UserManager<IdentityUser> _usrMgr;

  public Repository()
  {
    _ctx = new AppContext();
    _usrMgr = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_ctx));
  }

  public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string uName, string pWord)
  {
    // Setting the breakpoint here in this line below: 
    IdentityUser usr = await _usrMgr.FindAsync(uName, pWord);
    return user;
  }
}
```

On the breakpoint I've set on the Repository.cs, I see the error when I expand on the _usrMgr variable and check the Users property.

Update:
I found some bits of information here (on the section titled):

[Make the Type of Primary Key Be Extensible for Users and Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)

but I am unsure on how to implement this properly. Do I need to add a new class? The implementation there is quite vague in my understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, yes, you have to implement your own `IdentityUser` class. By default in Identity Framework `IdentityUser` id is of type `string`, which is not always acceptable. Therefore you can do the following:

```
public sealed class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```

where `int` is type of user Id. If you want to use your custom `UserLogin`, `UserRole` or `UserClaim` (by default their ids are also stings, so you probably also want to do that) then you have to add your custom inherited classes:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { } //int is id type
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { } //int is id type
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { } //int is id type
```

The next what you want to do is use your custom entity classes in all, provided by Identity, managers (like `UserManager` or `SignInManager`):

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User, int> {}
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<User, int> {}
```

where `User` type is your custom `User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>`(explained above) and `int` is id type. So, in two words, the basic idea is to inherit default Identity types with your own implementations and use them where Identity uses it's default types. This is OK practice. In your case, I suggest, `UniqueIdentifier` is some custom type so you have to use this type instead of `int` (like [in example you provided](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)):

```
public sealed class User : IdentityUser<UniqueIdentifier, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```